# UITouch equivalent for Mac

Tags: cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

I'm writing a Mac game using Cocos2D-iPhone, and need to get a click event. Is there an equivalent to UITouch for the Mac platform?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at both `NSEvent` and `NSTouch` - which isn't an exact match for `UITouch`, although close.

Comment: Worth noting that an NSTouch corresponds to a touch event, which is not the same as a click event. Not all of us even have multitouch-capable pointing devices on our Macs. On the Mac, touch input is a nice-to-have; it should never be the main way to do something. A click is completely encapsulated within an NSEvent (but make sure to distinguish between left-, right-, and middle-clicks, and single-, double-, and other multiple-clicks).

Answer (score 0):

[Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) (improved Cocos2D version) has a simple user input API: KKInput ([Class Reference](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Kobold2D/html/interface_k_k_input.html)). With that you can simply call at any time in any class or method:

```
[[KKInput sharedInput] isMouseButtonDown:kKKMouseButtonLeft];
```

KKInput offers the same convenient way to test for keyboard input, to get accelerometer (including filtering), gyroscope and device motion (attitude) values, and the current touches. It also supports Gesture Recognizers starting with Kobold2D Preview 5.